# CameraPreview is showing zoomed Image as compared with Instagram

Tags: java, android, android-camera, instagram

I am trying to make Image Capture screen just like instagram.

Here is my `SurfaceView` code

```
<SquareFrameLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:id="@+id/camLayout"
            />

SquareFrameLayout with measure overridden
@Override
    public void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec)
    {
        super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, widthMeasureSpec);
    }
```

This is my `SurfaceView` class:

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.hardware.Camera;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.SurfaceHolder;
import android.view.SurfaceView;

import java.util.List;

public class CameraView extends SurfaceView implements SurfaceHolder.Callback
{
    private static final String TAG = "CameraPreview";

    private Context mContext;
    private SurfaceHolder mHolder;
    private Camera mCamera;
    private List<Camera.Size> mSupportedPreviewSizes;
    private Camera.Size mPreviewSize;

    public CameraView(Context context, Camera camera)
    {
        super(context);
        mContext = context;
        mCamera = camera;

        // supported preview sizes
        mSupportedPreviewSizes = mCamera.getParameters().getSupportedPreviewSizes();
        for(Camera.Size str: mSupportedPreviewSizes)
            Log.e(TAG, str.width + "/" + str.height);

        // Install a SurfaceHolder.Callback so we get notified when the
        // underlying surface is created and destroyed.
        mHolder = getHolder();
        mHolder.addCallback(this);
        // deprecated setting, but required on Android versions prior to 3.0
        mHolder.setType(SurfaceHolder.SURFACE_TYPE_PUSH_BUFFERS);
    }

    public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {
        // empty. surfaceChanged will take care of stuff
    }

    public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder) {
        // empty. Take care of releasing the Camera preview in your activity.
    }

    public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format, int w, int h) {
        Log.e(TAG, "surfaceChanged => w=" + w + ", h=" + h);
        // If your preview can change or rotate, take care of those events here.
        // Make sure to stop the preview before resizing or reformatting it.
        if (mHolder.getSurface() == null){
            // preview surface does not exist
            return;
        }

        // stop preview before making changes
        try {
            mCamera.stopPreview();
        } catch (Exception e){
            // ignore: tried to stop a non-existent preview
        }

        // set preview size and make any resize, rotate or reformatting changes here
        // start preview with new settings
        try {
            Camera.Parameters parameters = mCamera.getParameters();
            parameters.setPreviewSize(mPreviewSize.width, mPreviewSize.height);
            mCamera.setParameters(parameters);
            mCamera.getParameters().setFocusMode(Camera.Parameters.FOCUS_MODE_AUTO);
            if(mCamera.getParameters().isZoomSupported())
                mCamera.getParameters().setZoom(0);
            mCamera.setPreviewDisplay(mHolder);
            mCamera.startPreview();

        } catch (Exception e){
            Log.d(TAG, "Error starting camera preview: " + e.getMessage());
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
        final int width = resolveSize(getSuggestedMinimumWidth(), widthMeasureSpec);
        final int height = resolveSize(getSuggestedMinimumHeight(), heightMeasureSpec);

        if (mSupportedPreviewSizes != null) {
            mPreviewSize = getOptimalPreviewSize(mSupportedPreviewSizes, width, height);
        }

        float ratio;
        if(mPreviewSize.height >= mPreviewSize.width)
            ratio = (float) mPreviewSize.height / (float) mPreviewSize.width;
        else
            ratio = (float) mPreviewSize.width / (float) mPreviewSize.height;

        // One of these methods should be used, second method squishes preview slightly
        setMeasuredDimension(width, (int) (width * ratio));
//        setMeasuredDimension((int) (width * ratio), height);
    }

    private Camera.Size getOptimalPreviewSize(List<Camera.Size> sizes, int w, int h) {
        final double ASPECT_TOLERANCE = 0.1;
        double targetRatio = (double) h / w;

        if (sizes == null)
            return null;

        Camera.Size optimalSize = null;
        double minDiff = Double.MAX_VALUE;

        int targetHeight = h;

        for (Camera.Size size : sizes) {
            double ratio = (double) size.height / size.width;
            if (Math.abs(ratio - targetRatio) > ASPECT_TOLERANCE)
                continue;

            if (Math.abs(size.height - targetHeight) < minDiff) {
                optimalSize = size;
                minDiff = Math.abs(size.height - targetHeight);
            }
        }

        if (optimalSize == null) {
            minDiff = Double.MAX_VALUE;
            for (Camera.Size size : sizes) {
                if (Math.abs(size.height - targetHeight) < minDiff) {
                    optimalSize = size;
                    minDiff = Math.abs(size.height - targetHeight);
                }
            }
        }

        return optimalSize;
    }
}
```

Here are the results. My image is kind of zoomed in. I am not sure what to do to make it similar.

[image]
[image]

Comment: I doubt that it's zoom-related issue. Most likely, that happens because you choose the wrong preview size here, and this can happen because your `camLayot` (which is the container of `CameraView`) has the form of square. Try to rewrite your code with the plain `FrameLayout` and see if it makes a difference.

Comment: @aga ok i made the app match parent instead of square view but instagram does capture image within a second. however if i am to crop image it takes time. how does insta handle it so fast.

Comment: Hard to tell without looking at the Instagram source code, which is proprietary. Maybe you can try to decompile their app and take a look at the sources.

Comment: Maybe they  are using the supported picture size which is as close to the cropped image as possible, so crop works very fast.

Comment: @aga i ahve confirmed now, my app has exact camera resolution and zoom like android camera app . However instagram is strangly showing zoomed out image. The preview size and surface holder size, i ahve tried t change both, it doesn't matter wether they are full screen or squared. They are still like android camera app but not like instagram :((((

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to OpenCamera Found here 
http://opencamera.sourceforge.net

i changed the Resolutions using following code

```
public Camera.Size getOptimalPreviewSize(List<Camera.Size> sizes)
    {
        final double ASPECT_TOLERANCE = 0.05;
        if( sizes == null )
            return null;

        Camera.Size optimalSize = null;
        double minDiff = Double.MAX_VALUE;
        Point display_size = new Point();
        Activity activity = (Activity)this.getContext();
        {
            Display display = activity.getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
            display.getSize(display_size);

            Log.d(TAG, "display_size: " + display_size.x + " x " + display_size.y);
        }
        double targetRatio = calculateTargetRatioForPreview(display_size);
        int targetHeight = Math.min(display_size.y, display_size.x);
        if( targetHeight <= 0 ) {
            targetHeight = display_size.y;
        }
        // Try to find the size which matches the aspect ratio, and is closest match to display height
        for(Camera.Size size : sizes)
        {
            Log.d(TAG, "    supported preview size: " + size.width + ", " + size.height);
            double ratio = (double)size.width / size.height;
            if( Math.abs(ratio - targetRatio) > ASPECT_TOLERANCE )
                continue;
            if( Math.abs(size.height - targetHeight) < minDiff ) {
                optimalSize = size;
                minDiff = Math.abs(size.height - targetHeight);
            }
        }
        if( optimalSize == null )
        {
            // can't find match for aspect ratio, so find closest one
            Log.d(TAG, "no preview size matches the aspect ratio");
            optimalSize = getClosestSize(sizes, targetRatio);
        }

            Log.d(TAG, "chose optimalSize: " + optimalSize.width + " x " + optimalSize.height);
            Log.d(TAG, "optimalSize ratio: " + ((double)optimalSize.width / optimalSize.height));
        return optimalSize;
    }


    private double calculateTargetRatioForPreview(Point display_size)
    {
        double targetRatio = 0.0f;

        if( isVideo)
        {

        }
        else
        {
            targetRatio = ((double)mCamera.getParameters().getPictureSize().width) / (double)mCamera.getParameters().getPictureSize().height;
            //targetRatio = ((double)display_size.x) / (double)display_size.y;
        }
        return targetRatio;
    }
```